# changing the div formation of the output retrieved via while loop

Tags: css, loops

i was thinking, how can I change the css options of different outputs in a loop?

for example, I am getting 10 results from a database, I want to change the color of the first 5 outputs to red, and add a photo of star beside each username..

Any ideas?

```
    $sql = "SELECT tele_members.Username, tele_members_results_k.Sum, tele_members_results_k.Correct, tele_members_results_k.Incorrect FROM `tele_members` LEFT JOIN `tele_members_results_k` ON tele_members.ID = tele_members_results_k.ID WHERE `Correct` - `Incorrect` > '0' ORDER BY `Sum` DESC";
    $query = mysql_query ($sql) or die("Error: " .$mysql_error());

    echo "<table width='639' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b>Логин:</b></td>";
    echo "<td><b>Правильные:</b></td>";
    echo "<td><b>Неправильные:</b></td>";
    echo "<td><b>Активность:</b></td>";
    echo "<td><b>Сумма:</td></b>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for (x=0; x>1; x++) { //I was trying to give the first row name "row1" and change the CSS options for "#row1"
        echo "<div id=row$x>";
        echo "<td>$row[Username]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Correct]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Incorrect]</td>";
$activity = $row[Correct] - $row[Incorrect]; //I wanted to calculate the number "quantity" of questions using the formula (correct) - (-incorrect)
        echo "<td>$activity</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Sum]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>$row[Username]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Correct]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Incorrect]</td>";
$activity = $row[Correct] - $row[Incorrect]; //I wanted to calculate the number "quantity" of questions using the formula (correct) - (-incorrect)
        echo "<td>$activity</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Sum]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
```

I hope this could help

Comment: Please post the code you have and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @j08691 I'll update the question, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, maybe like this ? run snippet or go forward to [jsfiddle - demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqedq135/11/)

```css
.block__item {
  background: #9c0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.block__item:nth-child(-n+5) {
  background: #455E00;
}
.block__item:nth-child(-n+5):before {
  content: '\2605';
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div>
    <div class="block__item">block-1</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-2</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-3</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-4</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-5</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-6</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-7</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-8</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-9</div>
    <div class="block__item">block-10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems reliable,but in the code that I've posted I used "for loop" to give the first DIV an id "row1".. do I need to keep it or using CSS we can control which div will be effected??

Comment: you don't need any specific id for first five blocks, as using css we can catch them

`div:nth-child(-n+5){
 here goes styles for first five blocks, you can change its styles, and add any icon using ::before psuedo-element
}`

Comment: Thank you sir you made my day, It's much simpler this way )) I'll mark it as an answer, because it did exactly what I'm looking for. thanks.